# Как читать спецификацию языка JSR-181?

Tags: java

Всем привет.

Очень глупый вопрос, знаю, но... ))

захожу вот на страничку [JCP](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=181), куда всё время поисковик ссылается, а там просто куча каких-то Maintenance Draft Review 2 и т.п...

как прочитать саму спецификацию-то? :) Куда нажимать?

Comment: @ MadCat45 Как вы думаете, по какой причине, программистам рекомендуют учить английский язык?

Comment: Вас интересуют строчки, содержащие слово Release,  чем свежее по дате - тем лучше. Draft - это черновые версии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Клик на "Download Page" в столбце Access. На открывшейся странице выбираешь нужное. Так же нажимаешь кнопку "Download" и затем скачиваешь pdf.